# error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'mongoose'

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-modules

I have mongoose installed it is showing in folder directory in node modules but If I try to check from VSCode it doesn't show mongoose folder inside node modules and while running npm start It shows that, "error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'mongoose'", I have been stuck in this problem since last 2-3 days.
Thanks for help.

I have tried uninstalling and installing mongoose but it doesn't work, also tried installing older version of mongoose but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your `package.json` file. I suspect you might not be installing `mongoose` at the root level of your project.